# Automate RealTek 8723de WiFi driver loading

Tags: wireless, realtek-wireless

On Ubuntu 19.04 with the rtl8723de driver, the first time WiFi works fine when the laptop is switched on, but if once disconnected, the WiFi does not connect again until the next restart of the computer.

I used the commands

```
sudo rmmod 8723de
sudo modprobe rtl8723de
```

and then it worked.
So, is there any way to automatically implement these commands?
And not having to type them again and again?